# Count rows which have value >0 for each column (in R)

Tags: r, matrix, rows

I have a large matrix (ma) I would like to count how many rows have value >0 for each column.

```
ma
   x    y  
a  0    3
b  0    0.1
c  2    2
d  0.3  1
```

RESULT

```
   x    y  
a  2    4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this solution with `base R`. One feature of matrices is that they can be easily indexed so that you can apply functions at row or column level like your question. Here the code:

```
#Code
colSums(ma>0)
```

Output:

```
colSums(ma>0)
x y 
2 4
```

Some data used:

```
#Data
ma <- structure(c(0, 0, 2, 0.3, 3, 0.1, 2, 1), .Dim = c(4L, 2L), .Dimnames = list(
    c("a", "b", "c", "d"), c("x", "y")))
```

You can also save the output like this:

```
#Save
res <- colSums(ma>0)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `apply` from `base R`

```
apply(ma >0, 2, sum)
```

---

Or with `sapply`

```
sapply(ma, function(x) sum(x > 0))
```

---

Or an option with `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
ma %>%
    summarise(across(everything(), ~ sum(. > 0)))
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `data.table` you can try

```
library(data.table)
set.DT(ma)
ma[,lapply(.SD, function(x) sum(x>0))]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
result<-apply(df >0, 2, sum)
```

[image]